# How to quickly train your agent to get a sense of the problem?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, dqn

I have a custom implementation of DQN. My robot/agent is running in Gazebo with ROS. Though I am trying a very simple task of pushing a cube, the DQN agent is taking too much time. DQN of 300 episode with step limit of 10 took 7.2 hours to train with worst performance. I suspect that the extremely slow training is mostly due to gazebo(+ joint trajectory controller, resetting controllers etc) and ROS. I want to nail down if I am facing one of the following problems:

1. Problem with my implementation of DQN
2. Problem is not well defined - For instance, state space is not defined well
3. Not enough training

DQN had two hidden layers with 64 and 32 neurons. Observation space is 9D, action space is 2D.

Exploration/Exploitation is handled using a decay epsilon greedy policy

```
max_exploration_rate = 1.0 
min_exploration_rate = 0.001 
exploration_decay_rate = 0.005 
exploration_rate = min_exploration_rate + (max_exploration_rate - min_exploration_rate) * np.exp(-exploration_decay_rate * episode_number)
if np.random.uniform(0, 1) < exploration_rate:
    explore
else:
    exploit
```

In an ideal case, the exploration/exploitation curve would look like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi @goldfinch! Could you please explain how your agent is handling the exploration vs. exploitation dilemma? For instance, are you using epsilon-greedy exploration?

Comment: @DeepQZero Yes, it is using epsilon-greedy exploration

Comment: How are you annealing epsilon? Does it start at 100% and decrease to a small value such as 5% or 2% over time? If so, how many steps does the annealing process take?

Comment: Hi @DeepQZero To answer that, I have edited the question, so that I can add few lines of code and a plot.

Comment: Have you tried different annealing rates, and other values for remaining hyperparameters? With slow rate of experience, you will want to be more aggressive about using the experience you have. Faster epsilon decay, faster switch of frozen target network, larger batch sizes

Comment: Also, at the really slow rate of an action every few seconds, it's worth saving *all* your data. Keep experience replay records from each run and combine them. Even if your goal is to make an agent that can learn from scratch in this kind of environment, that data has cost you a lot to collect and can be reused